# How to redirect from https://www.example.com to https://example.com in Deno Fresh?

Tags: deno, deno-deploy

I have a website deployed on [Deno deploy](https://deno.com/deploy) with a custom domain. I thought it would be possible to configure the appropriate redirects directly in the platform like I could do in for example, Vercel.

My question is: How can I configure redirects from https://www.example.com to https://example.com? Do I have to use `middleware` for this or is there another easier way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I know of currently to do this with [Deno Deploy](https://deno.com/deploy) is in your code.

Example from [Redirect | Examples | Deno](https://deno.com/deploy/docs/examples#redirect):

```
function handler(_req: Request) {
  return Response.redirect("https://example.com", 307);
}
```